# Impala command to know DB table size

Tags: hadoop, impala

Is there any way that we can check the DB table size and other properties ? I tried COMPUTE STATS but it gives the details of table except the size.
any link to find information and other details are much appreciated.

Comment: `show table stats tablename`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
show table stats tablename
```

Works as I wanted, Thanks alot